# How to use compare validator with a set of different values?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation, gridview

Q:

I have a gridview contains a textbox as a template field :

the aspx:

```
 <asp:GridView Width="100%" ID="gv_Evaluation" CssClass="datatable" AllowSorting="True"
 runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None"
 OnRowDataBound="gv_Evaluation_RowDataBound">
  <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="serial">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblSerial" runat="server"></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="activity type" DataField="activityType" />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="weight" DataField="activityWeight" />
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="evaluation">
      <ItemTemplate>
       <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txt_evaluateWeights" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
        OnTextChanged="txt_evaluateWeights_TextChanged"></telerik:RadTextBox>
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_evaluateWeights" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
 <RowStyle VerticalAlign="Top" CssClass="row" />
 </asp:GridView>
```

the weight column contains the following numbers`[50,10,10,10,5,5,10]`

What I wanna to do is:

Validate the data entry when the user enters the data in the `txt_evaluateWeights` Where it must be less than or equal the meeting one in the `weight` column. I do that in server side. But I wanna to do that client side. I tried to use the compare validator but it doesn't suit my case because each time i compare with a different value, according to the weight column.

Comment: Is txt_evaluateWeights a numeric input? If so, I would maybe look into using the RadNumericTextBox instead, as I think it has some of the features you need built-in.

Comment: yeah it's but this not the problem now. I wanna to validate each entry according to the opposite one in the `weight` column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CustomValidator` class and set the                 `ClientValidationFunction` property to use clientside validation

see [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx)